# how I can define typescript @type for exist component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I got jqwidgets-framework by npm:

*npm install jqwidgets-framework -D*

This framework have implemented a lot of react component by javascript.
For ex:

```
... 
export default class JqxCheckBox extends React.Component {
        componentDidMount() {
            let options = this.manageAttributes();
            this.createComponent(options);
        }; 
...
```

But my project wrote react by typescript so I can't integrate this framework to my project.

I'm trying add new file *jqw.d.ts*:

```
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/jqwidgets-framework/jqwidgets-ts/jqwidgets.d.ts" />

import * as React from "react";
import * as CSS from 'csstype';

interface IJqxCheckBoxProps extends jqwidgets.CheckBoxOptions {
    style?: CSS.Properties<string | number>;
    value: string;
    //on?: (name?: string, callback?: Function ) => void;
    // render?: ()=>void;
}
declare class JqxCheckBox extends React.Component<IJqxCheckBoxProps, any> { }

export default JqxCheckBox;
```

and use this component in react:

```
/// <reference path="jqw.d.ts"/>

import '../css/site.css';
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
//import 'jqwidgets-framework/jqwidgets-react/react_jqxdatatable';
import 'jqwidgets-framework/jqwidgets-react/react_jqxcheckbox';
import * as CSS from 'csstype';
.......
render() {
  let chexboxCSS: CSS.Properties<string | number> = { marginLeft: 10, float: 'left' };
  let checkboxParentCSS: CSS.Properties<string | number> = { float: 'left', width: 400, marginTop: 10 };
  return (
      <div style={{ fontFamily: 'Verdana Arial', fontSize: 12, width: 400 }}>
          <div style={{ float: 'left', width: 400 }}>
              <h3 style={{ marginLeft: 15 }}>Categories</h3>
              <JqxCheckBox style={chexboxCSS} value='Entertainment'
                  width={120} height={25}
              />
              <JqxCheckBox style={chexboxCSS} value='Computers'
                  width={120} height={25} checked={true}
              />
              <JqxCheckBox style={chexboxCSS} value='Sports'
                  width={120} height={25}
              />
.......
```

but it **do not** work.

How can I define type for exist components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [module declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#ambient-modules) to associate your type declarations with the original `jqwidgets-framework/jqwidgets-react/react_jqxcheckbox` module:

```
/// <reference path="node_modules/jqwidgets-framework/jqwidgets-ts/jqwidgets.d.ts" />

declare module "jqwidgets-framework/jqwidgets-react/react_jqxcheckbox" {
    import * as React from "react";
    import * as CSS from 'csstype';

    interface IJqxCheckBoxProps extends jqwidgets.CheckBoxOptions {
        style?: CSS.Properties<string | number>;
        value: string;
        //on?: (name?: string, callback?: Function ) => void;
        // render?: ()=>void;
    }
    class JqxCheckBox extends React.Component<IJqxCheckBoxProps, any> { }

    export default JqxCheckBox;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it work for me after I change import statement to:
_import JqxCheckBox from 'jqwidgets-framework/jqwidgets-react/react_jqxcheckbox';_